# yahoofinancials get_financial_stmts returns nothing

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying out the new(?) [yahoofinancials library](https://pypi.org/project/yahoofinancials/). I have not tried all the methods yet, but `get_financial_stmts` is not working for me. Does anyone have the same issue?

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('AAPL')
print(yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'income'))
```

Output:

```
{'incomeStatementHistory': {'AAPL': None}}
```

The other method I tried is `get_historical_price_data` and it's working fine.

Comment: I was able to get it correctly with colaboratory. `{'incomeStatementHistory': {'AAPL': [{'2020-09-26': {'researchDevelopment': 18752000000,... `

Comment: @r-beginners was there anything wrong with my code? I copied it straight from the library page ...

Comment: I copied your code verbatim and got the values.

Comment: The required library is beautifulsoup4,pytz, so is it up to date?

Comment: @r-beginners it's up to date. actually i think i applied some fixes that resulted in the error. I was able to fix the problem with this [fix](https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials/issues/75)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with this [fix](https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials/issues/75)